# Add character in middle of string

Tags: c

Been stuck on this for bloody ages. Seems like no easy way to do it!

Would appricate some help, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char (char *s, const int len) {
{
   static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                  "123456789";
   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[(sizeof(alphanum) - 6)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
    memmove(s+pos+1, s+pos, len-pos+1);
    s[pos]='-';
    puts(s);
}

int main (void)
{
//print the random digits but in the middle need to insert - e.g
//FJ3-FKE
}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `s[len] = 0;`...

Comment: Oh right, yes didn't realize lol

Comment: Please share what you have already tried

Comment: `"123456789";` is a statement with no effect. Did you mean to omit the semicolon between the letters and the numbers? Something like `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "123456789";` as C will concatenate these two for you.

Comment: Oh yes, silly mistake, cheers Nobilis

Comment: No need to thumbs down this question, +1. Is it just me, or have people on Stack have been hostile lately?

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy ways.

If you just need to *print* that stuff, you can add the dash just in the output, like this:

```
fwrite(s, pos, stdout);
putchar('-');
puts(s+pos);
```

In alternative, if the buffer used for `s` is big enough to accommodate one more `char`, you can use `memmove` to make space for the dash, add the dash and *then* print the string:

```
memmove(s+pos+1, s+pos, len-pos+1);
s[pos]='-';
puts(s);
```

(all this supposing that `pos` is the position where to insert the dash)

Comment: Well I really need to put it in a string, as I will be using it in a web request. Anyway to do that?

Comment: okay updated code will that be in the exact middle of 6 digits?

Comment: @ragingfire: please *read* the answer, check the documentation of the used functions and try to understand the code before doing a blind copy-paste...

Comment: Right so it copies from the second string where it adds - in the position to the first one, so I'm guessing I need to change the len position to 3. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void func(char *s, int len, int pos) {
    static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                   "123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand()%(sizeof(alphanum)-1)];
    }
    s[len] = 0;

    if(0 < pos && pos < len){
        memmove(s+pos+1, s+pos, len-pos+1);
        s[pos]='-';
    }
}

int main (void){
    char s[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
//print the random digits but in the middle need to insert - e.g
//FJ3-FKE
    func(s, 6, 3);
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```